# How to turn off report from built-in functions R

Tags: r, function

I have just finished building my own function. The problem is I use the function `top_n` from `dplyr` package in my function. Then when I run my function, it returns the report of the `top_n` (Figure). I wonder whether I can hide them? I try using like

```
invisible(capture.output(topgenename[[m]]<-rownames(dplyr::top_n(data.frame(kurt1[,m]),3))))
```

But it just adjusts the color of the report (black to red, Figure).

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the message by specifying the variable name explicitly in `top_n`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% top_n(3)

#Selecting by carb #<- See the message
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Duster 360          14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.8  0  0    3    4
#...
#...


mtcars %>% top_n(3, carb)
#Message gone
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Duster 360          14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.8  0  0    3    4
#...
#...
```

Side note, `top_n` has been super-seeded with  `slice_max`/`slice_min` and will return an error if you don't specify the variable name.

```
mtcars %>% slice_max(n = 3)
```

> Error: argument `order_by` is missing, with no default.

```
mtcars %>% slice_max(n = 3, carb)
```

Comment: Wow, the solution is easier than my thought! All I need to do is add the variable name to the parameter `wt` of the `top_n`! Thanks, sir!